# How Do I Make A Tampermonkey Userscript Replace Words In Text Files?

Tags: tampermonkey, userscripts

6 years ago I asked a question about rewriting text files displayed in a browser using greasemonkey.
[Can I Make Greasmonkey Scripts Run On Text Files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26387485/can-i-make-greasmonkey-scripts-run-on-text-files)

I am now coming back to a similar problem and I tried to paste it in to Tampermonkey but it doesn't replace the text.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Rewrite LLVM License
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @match        http://llvm.org/releases/2.8/*
// @include      http://llvm.org/releases/2.8/LICENSE.TXT
// @require      http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    //Just to tell the linter that $ is defined in jquery
    /* global $ */

    //Browsers display text in a pre tag
    var pageTextNd=$("body > pre");

    //Replace the text LLVM
    var newPageTxt=pageTextNd.text().replace("LLVM", "Ernst Blofeld");

    //Rewrite the page
    pageTextNd.text(newPageTxt);
})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the page you're interested in redirects to:

```
https://releases.llvm.org/2.8/LICENSE.TXT
```

so that's what you need to set your `@include` or `@match` to.

You also want to replace *all* instances of LLVM, so use [`.replaceAll`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58443263):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Rewrite LLVM License
// @include      https://releases.llvm.org/2.8/LICENSE.TXT
// @require      http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    //Just to tell the linter that $ is defined in jquery
    /* global $ */

    //Browsers display text in a pre tag
    var pageTextNd=$("body > pre");

    //Replace the text LLVM
    var newPageTxt=pageTextNd.text().replaceAll("LLVM", "Ernst Blofeld");

    //Rewrite the page
    pageTextNd.text(newPageTxt);
})();
```

If you don't want to rely on `replaceAll`, use a regular expression with `.replace` instead: `/LLVM/g`.

It seems quite strange to rely on jQuery for something this trivial though - you can very easily accomplish this without a library:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Rewrite LLVM License
// @include      https://releases.llvm.org/2.8/LICENSE.TXT
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

const pre = document.querySelector('body > pre');
pre.textContent = pre.textContent.replaceAll('LLVM', "Ernst Blofeld");
```